# Use loop to create lists inside another list

Tags: r, list

I would like to create two lists inside another list. Normally I will have to create 50 each one for a state of USA and I'm looking for a way to make it faster.

```
State <- c("ALABAMA", "ALABAMA", "ALASKA", "ALASKA")
Num <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)
d <- data.frame(State, Num)

uni<-unique(d$State)

data = list(
  for(i in 1 : length(uni)){
    list[[i]](
      name = un[i],
      y = summarise(sum(d$Num[D$State==uni[i]])),
      drilldown = tolower(un[i])
    )
  }
)
```

More specifically I want each list to include the `name` of the `State` in Capital letters, `y` as the sum of the `Num` and `drilldown` as the name of the `State` in non capital letters. The result should be something like:

```
name="ALABAMA"
y= 11
drilldown="alabama"

name="ALASKA"
y= 15
drilldown="alaska"
```

Manually it would be like :

```
data = list(

      list(
        name = "ALABAMA",
        y = 11,
        drilldown = "alabama"
      ),
      list(
        name = "ALASKA",
        y = 15,
        drilldown = "alaska"
      )

    )
```

which gives a list of 2 lists of 3 objects.

It may be possible without `for()`so Im open to other suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
State <- c("ALABAMA", "ALABAMA", "ALASKA", "ALASKA")
Num <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)
d <- data.frame(State, Num, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

**Solution 1 : `Use built-in packages`**

```
df1 <- within(aggregate(Num ~ State, d, FUN = sum), drilldown <- tolower(State))
output1 <- lapply(split(df1, 1:nrow(df1)), c)
str(output1)

# List of 2
#  $ 1:List of 3
#   ..$ State    : chr "ALABAMA"
#   ..$ Num      : num 11
#   ..$ drilldown: chr "alabama"
#  $ 2:List of 3
#   ..$ State    : chr "ALASKA"
#   ..$ Num      : num 15
#   ..$ drilldown: chr "alaska"
```

**Solution 2 : `library(tidyverse)`**

```
output2 <- d %>% group_by(State) %>%
                 summarise(Num = sum(Num)) %>%
                 mutate(drilldown = tolower(State)) %>% 
                 transpose  # purrr::transpose
str(output2)

# List of 2
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ State    : chr "ALABAMA"
#   ..$ Num      : num 11
#   ..$ drilldown: chr "alabama"
#  $ :List of 3
#   ..$ State    : chr "ALASKA"
#   ..$ Num      : num 15
#   ..$ drilldown: chr "alaska"
```

Comment: I made an edit. Yous solution gives  1 list with 2 'list of 3' while I would like 2 lists.

Comment: @firmo23 I don't understand the difference between the output you edited and mine.

Answer (score 3):

You can run a quick `rowsum()` to get the group sums, then `Map()` to assemble the list from its parts.

```
xx <- with(d, rowsum(Num, State))
Map(list, name=rownames(xx), y=xx, drilldown=tolower(rownames(xx)), USE.NAMES=FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$name
# [1] "ALABAMA"
#
# [[1]]$y
# [1] 11
#
# [[1]]$drilldown
# [1] "alabama"
#
#
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$name
# [1] "ALASKA"
#
# [[2]]$y
# [1] 15
#
# [[2]]$drilldown
# [1] "alaska"
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like the following? It uses `split` to make a list of dataframes, one per `State` and then `lapply` an anonymous function to each of the df's.

Here are two versions, with different output formats, an object of class `"list"` an an object of class `"data.frame"`.

```
lapply(split(d, d$State), function(DF){
  s <- as.character(DF[["State"]][1])
  list(
    State = s,
    y = sum(DF[["Num"]]),
    drilldown = tolower(s)
  )
})

lapply(split(d, d$State), function(DF){
  s <- as.character(DF[["State"]][1])
  data.frame(
    State = s,
    y = sum(DF[["Num"]]),
    drilldown = tolower(s)
  )
})
```

**EDIT.**

The first way outputs a list of two *named* lists. If you want those lists to be unnamed, do what [G. Grothendiek comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853012/use-loop-to-create-lists-inside-another-list/54853136#comment96479626_54853136) proposes.

```
data <-lapply(unname(split(d, d$State)), function(DF){
  s <- as.character(DF[["State"]][1])
  list(
    State = s,
    y = sum(DF[["Num"]]),
    drilldown = tolower(s)
  )
})
```

Comment: I made an edit. Yous solution gives  1 list with 2 'list of 3' while I would like 2 lists.

Comment: This could be written: `lapply(unname(split(d, d$State)), with, list(name = State[1], y = tolower(State[1]), drilldown = sum(Num)))`

Comment: @firmo23 My first solution does output a list of **two** lists. Anyway, I have edited, see if this is it.

Answer (score 2):

Using a for-loop is indeed not the best option here, because it tends to be both slow and hard to read.

This kind of task is perfect for the `dplyr` package using pipes:

```
library(dplyr)

df_result <- d %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  summarise(y = sum(Num),
            drilldown = tolower(first(State)))

print(df_result)
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  State       y drilldown
  <fct>   <dbl> <chr>    
1 ALABAMA    11 alabama  
2 ALASKA     15 alaska
```

If you want to achieve a nested list like in your example output instead of a data.frame, you can additionally use `transpose()` from the `purrr` package:

```
library(purrr)

transpose(df_result)
```

gives:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$State
[1] "ALABAMA"

[[1]]$y
[1] 11

[[1]]$drilldown
[1] "alabama"


[[2]]
[[2]]$State
[1] "ALASKA"

[[2]]$y
[1] 15

[[2]]$drilldown
[1] "alaska"
```

Comment: Nice work! But the expected output should be a list, not a data frame. Maybe you can  add some commands to transform it.

Comment: I made an edit. Yous solution gives  1 list with 2 'list of 3' while I would like 2 lists.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understand. As far as I can tell, this leads to the exact same result as what you gave as your 'manual solution'. Could you be more specific?